# Exporting password protected file from sql

Tags: file, passwords, export, protected

How can I export my MSSQL table into a password protected excel file? I am mentioning that I need to export my table into excel not importing.

Answer (score 0):

Export the MSSQL data into excel by following the steps mentioned here
[Export SQL server data to Excel](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-import-and-export-sql-server-data-to-an-excel-file/) and then add a password to your generated excel using the steps mentioned in this article [Protect Excel with a Password](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/protect-an-excel-file-7359d4ae-7213-4ac2-b058-f75e9311b599)